# Can't change text of a link with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code some link but I cannot change the text with jquery.

I tried

```
  if($("a").text() == 'some link') {
   $("a").text('success');
  }
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a broad problem.  Are there any errors?  Do you have any links that actually have text with `'some link'`?  What is happening and what do you expect?

Comment: Do you have any anchor (a) tags on the page? Does the *first* one have the text of "some link"?

Comment: do you want to change text of all a tags for any particular one?

Comment: Are you sure that if($("a").text() == 'some link') is true?

Comment: Please show some html code where the <a> is

Comment: Working for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/uEMgt/

Comment: Palash that wont work if you have multiple <a> tags

Answer (score 4):

Do this

```
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).text()=="some link"){
      $(this).text("success");
  }
});
```

This will look through all a tags one by one and check if they have the "some link". With your code you are looking through all a tags and the text might be "link1link2link3link4"

Comment: This probably is the point, well spotted. Whough I would like to remark that the texts from the anchors will not get concatenated. It is the _first_ matchs text that is chosen, isn't it?

Comment: I think they get concatenated, i just tested on my site and it added all the strings together.

Comment: Can I maybe get to it using the TITLE attr?

Comment: this function looks for any a tag containing the text "some link" if you want to look for a tag that contains the link "some link" you must use if($(this).attr('href'){}

Comment: if you want to get it using the title attr do this $(a[title="titletexthere"]')

Comment: <a href="http://mysite.com/index.php/amlist/list/" title="My Gallery">My Gallery</a>

Comment: to find that you can use this $('a[title="My Gallery"]') or $('a:contains("My Gallery")') or $('a[href="mysite.com/index.php/amlist/list/"]')

Comment: I tried if ($('a:contains("My Gallery")') {
$(this).text('success');
} but it's not working. example please?

Comment: The damn thing keeps returning a:contains is NULL. Same problem as before, like it doesn't exist (though I copy/pasted the HTML. What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you find any div with jQuery or does it also return null?

Comment: Then im not entirely sure what is wrong, if you could show some more html then i might see the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **links**, then you should get the "href" attribute using the attr property

```
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('href')=="some link"){
      $(this).text("success");
  }
});
```

I hope this helps.